how to extract files from a list using substring filter
I have a list of files from os.listdir like:
 TXSHP_20240712052921.csv
 TXSHP_20240715045301.csv
 TXSHP_FC_20210323084010.csv
 TXSHP_FC_20231116060918.csv

how do I extract only the ones where 'FC' is not in the filename
Ive tried
def get_archive_filelist_chip(archiveFldr):
    nonedi_files_chip = []
    folder = archiveFldr
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        if  file.endswith(".csv") & 'FC' in file == False:
            nonedi_files_chip.append(file)
        else:
            pass
    #nonedi_files_chip = filter(lambda x: 'FC' not in x, nonedi_files_chip)
    return nonedi_files_chip


Try ('FC' in File == False)

It's almost always wrong to compare explicitly with True or False. Just use in or not in.

What's the reason for folder = archiveFldr? Do you think you're not allowed to pass the parameter directly to another function, you have to give it a new name?

There's no need for else: pass. Did someone tell you that every if needs an else:?

if  file.endswith(".csv") & 'FC' in file == False:

Observe that bitwise AND (&) in python is more sticky than in (see Operator precedence table) so your condition is understood as
if (file.endswith(".csv") & 'FC') in file == False:

You should use boolean AND in this case and brackets (which will also help reader understand your code)
if file.endswith(".csv") and ('FC' in file == False):

though it in python not in is often used for such task, that is
if file.endswith(".csv") and 'FC' not in file:


I tried all these methods out and none of them returned anything

@BenSmith The last should definitely work. You must have made some other mistake.
